# Jackson ReadValue doesn't convert to List<>

Tags: java, reflection, jackson

I have a problem. I work with custom annotation, which takes method params and converts them from json to pojo. Here is example:

```
...
MethodParameter param 
// here a parameter from methods, marked with custom annotation
...
JSON_MAPPER.readValue(node, param.getParameterType());

java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.KeyValuePair
```

But when I try to convert List<> it doesn't work. But the code below works fine

```
JSON_MAPPER.readValue(node, new TypeReference<List<KeyValuePair>>(){});
```

how I can figure out the type of income data? What should I do?

Comment: What's the method signature?

Comment: List<KeyValuePair> settings - It's marked with custom annotation in controller method, and then goes to the my custom annotation implementation @SotiriosDelimanolis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume your method looks something like

```
public List<KeyValuePair> methodName(..) {..}
```

In other words, its return type is what you want the JSON to be parsed as.

I'm also going to assume that `MethodParameter` is [`org.springframework.core.MethodParameter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/MethodParameter.html). You'll notice that [`MethodParameter#getParameterType()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/MethodParameter.html#getParameterType--) returns a `Class<?>`. In this case, it will return the `Class` object for the `List` type.

Given a `List.class`, there's no way for Jackson to guess what the element type will be. As such, it uses its default `LinkedHashMap`.

Use the [`MethodParameter#getGenericParameterType()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/MethodParameter.html#getGenericParameterType--) method which will return a `Type` object completely describing the `List<KeyValuePair>` return type. Jackson will have enough type information from that to build an appropriate object from the JSON.

You'll need to transform the `Type` into a `JavaType` expected by [`ObjectMapper#readValue`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readValue-java.io.Reader-com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType-).

```
mapper.readValue(node, mapper.getTypeFactory().constructType(param.getGenericParameterType()));
```

Comment: I tried to use something like `JSON_MAPPER.readValue(node,param.getGenericParameterType());` but it doesn't work, because param.getGenericParameter returns Type, not Class, because readValue doesn't accept Type.

Comment: @jahra Sorry, I confused it with Gson, which does accept `Type`. With Jackson, just use the `TypeFactory` to construct a `JavaType`. I've edited with details.

Comment: It works! It's like Hogwards magic but works! Thank you a lot, you saved me:) But I have a question. Will it work if param will be not generic, but simple String or another Class Type?

Comment: @jahra It should. If the return type isn't generic, it will just return the corresponding `Class` object. `Class` is a subtype of `Type`.